# Something wrong with output from list in Python

Tags: python, list, text

I want a Python program to import a list of words from a text file and print out the content of the text file as two lists. The data in the text file is on this form:

```
A Alfa
B Betta
C Charlie
```

I want a Python program to print out one list with A,B,C and one with Alfa, Betta, Charlie.

This is what I've written:

```
english2german = open('english2german.txt', 'r')
englist = []
gerlist = []

for i, line in enumerate(english2german):
    englist[i:], gerlist[i:] = line.split()
```

This is making two lists, but will only print out the first letter in each word.
How can I make my code to print out the whole word?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
english2german = open("english2german.txt")
englist = []
gerlist = []

for line in english2german:
    (e, g) = line.split()
    englist.append(e)
    gerlist.append(g)
```

The problem with your code before is that `englist[i:]` is actually a *slice* of a list, not just a single index. A string is also iterable, so you were basically stuffing a single letter into several indices. In other words, something like `gerlist[0:] = "alfa"` actually results in `gerlist = ['a', 'l', 'f', 'a']`.

Answer (score 6):

And even shorter than [amo-ej1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743248/something-wrong-with-output-from-list-in-python/743274#743274), and likely faster:

```
In [1]: english2german = open('english2german.txt')
In [2]: eng, ger = zip(*( line.split() for line in english2german ))
In [3]: eng
Out[3]: ('A', 'B', 'C')
In [4]: ger
Out[4]: ('Alfa', 'Betta', 'Charlie')
```

If you're using Python 3.0 or `from future_builtins import zip`, this is memory-efficient too.  Otherwise replace `zip` with `izip` from `itertools` if `english2german` is very long.

Comment: That's.. horrible. It might be faster, but I really doubt it's "usefully-faster", and it's far harder to read (the * especially)

Comment: it's the 'unzip' operation, it's a fairly common idiom to join up pairs of things.

Comment: I've benchmarked the zip method against the code in mipadi's answer. zip is slightly slower with a small set of data, but slightly quicker with 10,000 lines... but the difference is about 0.05 on each..

Answer (score 3):

just an addition: you're working with files.
please close them :) or use the with construct:

```
with open('english2german.txt') as english2german:
  englist, gerlist = zip(*(line.split() for line in english2german))
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this you mean:

```
english2german = open('k.txt', 'r')
englist = []
gerlist = []

for i, line in enumerate(english2german):
    englist.append(line.split()[0])
    gerlist.append(line.split()[1])

print englist
print gerlist
```

which generates:

['A', 'B', 'C']
['Alfa', 'Betta', 'Charlie']

Answer (score 1):

The solutions already posted are OK if you have no spaces in any of the words (ie each line has a single space). If I understand correctly, you are trying to build a dictionary, so I would suggest you consider the fact that you can also have definitions of multiple word expressions. In that case, you'd better use some other character instead of a space to separate the definition from the word. Something like "|", which is impossible to appear in a word.

Then, you do something like this:

```
for line in english2german:
    (e, g) = line.split("|")
    englist.append(e)
    gerlist.append(g)
```

Comment: -1: changing the file format.  Use parition instead of split -- same effect--no change to the file format.

Comment: Oh well, I didn't say he *has* to change the file format! I just *suggested*. I don't really see how partition can fix the problem I described, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly meta-answer(?) to [Autoplectic's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743248/something-wrong-with-output-from-list-in-python/743313#743313) suggestion of using `zip()`

With 3 lines in the input file (from the supplied data in the question):

The `zip()` method takes an average of `0.404729390144` seconds, compared to `0.341339087486` with the simple for loop constructing two lists (the code from [mipadi's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743248/something-wrong-with-output-from-list-in-python/743268#743268) currently accepted answer).

With 10,000 lines in the input file (random generated 3-12 character words. I reduced the `timeit.repeat()` values to 100 times, repeated twice):

`zip()` took an average of `1.43965339661` seconds, compared to `1.52318406105` with the for loop.

Both benchmarks were done using Python version 2.5.1

Hardly a huge difference.. Given how much more readable the simple for loop is, I would recommend using it.. The `zip` code might be a bit quicker with large files, but the difference is about 0.083 seconds with 10,000 lines..

Benchmarking code:

```
import timeit

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743248/something-wrong-with-output-from-list-in-python/743313#743313
code_zip = """english2german = open('english2german.txt')
eng, ger = zip(*( line.split() for line in english2german ))
"""

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743248/something-wrong-with-output-from-list-in-python/743268#743268
code_for = """english2german = open("english2german.txt")
englist = []
gerlist = []

for line in english2german:
    (e, g) = line.split()
    englist.append(e)
    gerlist.append(g)
"""

for code in [code_zip, code_for]:
    t = timeit.Timer(stmt = code)
    try:
        times = t.repeat(10, 10000)
    except:
        t.print_exc()
    else:
        print "Code:"
        print code
        print "Time:"
        print times
        print "Average:"
        print sum(times) / len(times)
        print "-" * 20
```